# Why Hazelcast CacheLoader class needs to be visible by all clients?

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, distributed-cache

Currently I'm discovering the Hazelcast technology. I'm trying to implement it in a system combined with multiple clients apps and one central server.

The server is the only provider of data from an external source. The data is cached by the Hazelcast ICache and loaded at request of Hazelcast client by a class implementing the CacheLoaded interface.

The CacheLoader implementor has to be in clients classpathes (I get ClassNotFoundException if I remove it) and this is the thing I don't understand... If a Hazelcast client is connected to the server, the CacheLoader is invoked on the server side. Moreover I don't know the implementation would look like if it's dependant on i.e. server database.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: this seems like a bug to me. CacheLoaders shouldn't be needed in clients. Could you please open an issue for this at https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/new ? Thanks!

Comment: it really is a bug. See https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/6676
the fix is on the way. many thanks for reporting it!